# What is the use of MsoTriState? And how is it important in adding a picture using VBA?

Tags: ms-office

I was researching on how to attach a picture in an excel spreadsheet using VBA and found that `shapes.addpicture` worked. This has arguments such as `filename` and `LinkToFile` and `SaveToDocument` as `MsoTristate`.

Now on doing further research online, I find that MsoTristate is a 3-state Boolean value. OK. I can grasp the concept.

But I cannot understand as to how it is used and also why I would need a boolean value to link a file or save a document. Also, what other uses could such a thing have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well actually it can be more than 3 states! From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.msotristate?view=office-pia) we see that aside from the plain old True and False, all other values are *not* supported in the Case of MS Office. So in your case, you can safely assume it functions as a boolean.

Depending on the specific function evoked, the booleans are just parameters or options. For instance in [`fromImage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromfile?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Image_FromFile_System_String_System_Boolean_) you pass a String (PATH to file) and a Boolean which tells MSoffice if you want to use color management.

Comment: The documantation linked to here is for `.Net`.  the `VBA` version is [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msotristate)